# Problema al eliminar registro de base de datos en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

tengo una tabla html en mi vista con un botón 'delete' para cada renglón que me cambia el campo 'canceled' a true para marcarlo como que ha sido borrado porque no quiero que se borre de mi base de datos.
El problema es que me tira un error que es el siguiente:

```
undefined method `canceled=' for nil:NilClass
```

Mi boton esta realizado de la siguiente manera en mi vista:

```
<td><%= link_to t('Cancelar'), [turns],method: :delete,data: 
{ confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></td>
```

Y en mi controlador tengo el siguiente metodo:

```
def destroy @turn.canceled = true @turn.save end
```

Answer (score 1):

Por favor prueba esto:

```
<td><%= link_to t('Cancelar'), @turn,method: :delete,data: 
{ confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></td>
```

por supuesto

Verifica que adicionalmente tengas esto en tu controlador:

```
... 
before_action :set_turn, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
...

...
private
    def set_turn
        @turn = Turn.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Asumiento que tu modelo se llame `Turn` y tu modelo tenga el campo `canceled`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @BugBuster, pero lo que deseaba hacer era una eliminación lógica cambiando el estado de un campo tipo bool nada mas. Saludos.

Comment: Si eso lo vi, es parte de tu logica y tus razones procedimentales tendras y por supuesto se respeta.

Answer (score 0):

En mi método destroy del controlador de Turns escribí el siguiente código y me funciono como deseaba:

```
def destroy
@turn=Turn.update(:canceled => true)
flash[:notice] = 'Turno cancelado con éxito!' 
redirect_to show_url
end
```

Mi boton 'cancelar' ubicado en la vista index de turns quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
<td><%= link_to t('Cancelar'), turns,method: :delete,data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></td>
```

Comment: Estimado Franco, con el respeto que tu codigo se merece,tu codigo camina, es cierto, pero en Ruby y RoR tenemos algo llamado CoC, que es basicamente privilegir la convencion sobre la configuracion, aqui un enlace sobre que es esto de la CoC https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenci%C3%B3n_sobre_configuraci%C3%B3n esto es para faciliar el mantenimiento al Franco del futuro u otros desarrolladores que tengan que hacer mantenimiento al codigo, saludos.

Comment: Secundo a BugBuster respecto a lo del CoC. Creo que quedaría mejor si crearas otro action `cancel` en tu controlador que realizara la acción que esperas. A futuro quizás necesites borrar realmente y debas mover la lógica de cancelar. Si, no es algo grave, pero es un tema de orden o estilo de programación que si te acostumbras, puede ahorrarte un par de dolores de cabeza a futuro. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por las sugerencias, voy a intentar hacerlo de esa manera. Saludos.

Comment: Si yo defino un action 'cancelar' en mi controlador, como acciono ese action desde el boton 'cancelar' que tengo en mi vista ?